# Why is there a notch in the Na curve for an action potential?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, action-potential

Just out of curiosity, why does the Na curve dip down like in the figure below? I can't seem to find an explanation!

[image: ion currents during action potentials]

Comment: AP? Please do not use non-standard abbreviations in questions, especially in titles as they defy the indexing system this site relies on and confuse readers.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the source of your figures — you should always include reference information for quotes and images. Also, are you asking about the left panel or the right panel ? ——— I made what I believe to be corrections to your title (nudge makes no sense in this context) — please check that the new wording is consistent with what you were trying to ask.